# Jasper/Dynamic reports multiply subtotal by number (dynamic-report, not JRXML)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

Is it possible to multiply subtotal with specified number in Jasper/Dynamic reports? I have sum in subtotal and I would like to have a possibility to enter discount before start report and I would like to see it in my report. Is there any way to create variable and multiply or divide subtotal?
For example:

```
report.subtotalsAtSummary(sbt.sum(colUnits)*myCreatedNumber);
```

How can I create "myCreatedNumber"? Because sbt.sum(colUnits.multiply(column)) works only with columns and I want to multiply with number.

I see that there are many people who are smart enough, to not understand what I am asking without a code sample and giving me minuses, but I will try to explain a little bit more. Lets say that I have a invoice with sum of money in subtotal. But I want to give a discount which I set manually, the discount is not stored in DataSource. How can I create variable in Dynamic/Jasper reports in Java?

ADDITION
I have tried this:

```
int cc = 15;
report.addParameter("par1", cc);
Integer xxx = (Integer) report.getJasperParameters().get("par1");
```

But when I uncomment last line report shows empty. If I add JOption pane to show xxx it shows 15, but report is still empty.

Comment: I'm correct stating that you need a solution in dynamic-report not a jrxml solution, please also consider improving your question with some example data, example output of what you need..

Comment: I have corrected my question. I believe that for those, who knows the answer code, that I added, is enough

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured it out.
I couldn't find how to insert my own nuber to the report, but there is possibility to create variables in report using custom variables, created with class methods. Good example, which helped me a lot, of creating custom variables is at [dynamic reports page](http://dynamicreports.org/examples/variablereport).